# Liferay portlet version management?

Tags: configuration, liferay, portlet

I want manage portlets version. But I don't know how display it properly.
I want display portlet version in version label in App Manager, but when I create a portlet, the version is set in portlet title and not in version label.

However, when I create a service builder, the version is set in version label.

Comment: It would help if you would show how you've created the portlet.

Comment: I use the wizard of ellipse given by Liferay. I create a Liferay Plugin project with build type Maven and plugin type Portlet.